# Google Swiffy method can export in SVG shapes instead of Canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, svg, google-swiffy

I want to export swf into SVG animation.
This website already used swiffy and runtime generating svg shapes.
http://gardenestudio.com.br/1-ano/

But When I convert my swf file into html 5 using swiffy it exporting animation in Canvas.

Please guide me how to get swiffy animation into SVG shapes.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Swiffy website, [**Release notes, August 4, 2014 (version 7.0.0)**](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/releasenotes.html) :

> Switched to HTML Canvas for renderering *[sic]*
>   rather than SVG. This allows improved fidelity for filters and other
>   graphical effects and provides more consistent results across a
>   broader range of platforms including mobile devices.

Since the Swiffy extension in Flash accesses Google Swiffy as a web service, "[you always use the most recent version of Swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/extension.html)". So, if the most recent version of Swiffy has switched from SVG to canvas, then I guess you're stuck with it.

Comment: I am working on this project: http://luregalore.in/demo/koba4 (demo version animated by css3).
Home page menu flip animation i wanted to make using google swiffy. because it's performance is mind blowing 
But new version exporting Canvas because of that i can't fire my event on specific menu.

Also svg support Height="auto" which will be helpful for fluid website. canvas height auto will not accept.

Please guide me correct method

Comment: Please guide me best and easy method to get 100% smooth result for A menu flip to B menu and B to C then + + + kind animation.